# Can i give my customer an AWS bucket link where they can go and upload files?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

We want to get the files from our customers in our S3 bucket, I want to know if it's possible to create a bucket and give it's link to the customer so that he can upload the files to that bucket.

Answer (score 3):

The thing that you are looking for is Signed URLs. Here you can read more: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-signed-urls.html
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/PresignedUrlUploadObject.html

The important thing to note is that this signed url is going to be valid for a specific time.

Comment: I can use signed URLs for accessing or downloading a file. I want to generate a URL where my clients can upload their files to my s3 bucket.

Comment: Yes. Signed Urls can be used for that as well. Here you can read more https://sanderknape.com/2017/08/using-pre-signed-urls-upload-file-private-s3-bucket/

Answer (score 0):

You can share a bucket with others, with security policies as defined in your Bucket Policy and IAM Policies. However, keep in mind that you'd be charged for their usage. You can use S3 Requester Pays to invert request charges, but storage charges still apply to the bucket owner.